# Binding ElementName. Does it use Visual Tree or Logical Tree

Tags: wpf, binding, elementname, visual-tree, logical-tree

Having `{Binding ElementName=foo}`, will it lookup visual or logical tree?

[Of logical and visual trees in WPF | Data See, Data Do](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2008/05/23/of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-wpf/)

> When does the logical tree matter?
>
> When looking up a name, such as in
>   {Binding ElementName=Foo}, the search
>   walks up the ancestry looking for a
>   name scope, again just as it does for
>   inheritable properties.

[ElementName binding in Silverlight via Attached Behaviours](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/02/22/elementname-binding-in-silverlight-via-attached-behaviours.html)

> In order to enable this, WPF provides
>   ElementName and RelativeSource
>   bindings, giving you a powerful
>   mechanism for locating other elements
>   within your visual tree to bind to

**EDIT:**

It looks like the Logical Tree used for binding by `ElementName`.

Argument # 1.

According to MSDN article [FrameworkElement Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx):

> FrameworkElement extends UIElement
>   and adds the following capabilities:
>
> - Support for data binding and
>     dynamic resource references: The
>     property-level support for data
>     binding and resources is implemented
>     by the DependencyProperty class and
>     embodied in the property system, but
>     the ability to resolve a member value
>     that is stored as an Expression (the
>     programming construct that underlies
>     both data binding and dynamic
>     resources) is implemented by
>     FrameworkElement. For more
>     information, see Data Binding Overview
>     and Resources Overview.

Argument # 2.

`ElementName` points to `x:Name`, so this name should be found some how. There is a [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.aspx) concept.

> For most scenarios, the FindName
>   methods exposed on FrameworkElement
>   and FrameworkContentElement are more
>   appropriate methods to call to search
>   for elements by name. The Name
>   properties exposed by FrameworkElement
>   and FrameworkContentElement are more
>   appropriate properties to use to set
>   the initial name as markup attributes.
>   And the RegisterName methods exposed
>   on FrameworkElement and
>   FrameworkContentElement is necessary
>   to establish a name into a specific
>   namescope (there is no NameScope
>   member that can do this directly; you
>   must set the current namescope first
>   to use RegisterName).

On the other hand, [Visual class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx) neither have `FindName` method, nor implement [INameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.inamescope.aspx).

Comment: Logical-Tree used. Will post details latter.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's logical tree.  When using ControlTemplates, you're replacing one visual tree with another, but I don't think you can reference the names defined inside of the ControlTemplate.

For example:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="Foo" TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="Red">
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></Label>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="buttonFoo" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Template="{DynamicResource Foo}">Foo</Button>
        <Label x:Name="labelBar" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=Background}">Bar</Label>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Doesn't find the element named "border" in the ControlTemplate, but changing ElementName in labelBar's binding to "buttonFoo" makes the Background Green, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `ElementName` property of a binding *in a sense (see below answer)* works off of the logical tree because one is using `ElementName` to divine a specific control solely on the logical tree in the Xaml.

> will it lookup visual or logical tree?

The premise you propose is wrong, there is no *lookup* per-se on either tree. One is simply setting a **Source** property for reflection operation used by the binding instead of defaulting to the inherited `DataContext` of the logical tree.

If one reads the documentation of [Binding.ElementName Property (System.Windows.Data)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (bolding mine):

> "...the ElementName property is one of the ways you can explicitly set the **source** of a Binding and override the inherited data context."

The source is **any instantiated object** which is within the current operations namespace which can be accessed and reflected off of.

No more no less and most likely will be in the Logical Tree (but doesn't have too) because people *name* there logical items in Xaml, but also could be in the visual tree.

---

See [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.