# Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I get this error:

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''
```

On this Binding:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsVisible,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

The `ViewModel` is sitting as `DataContext` in `UserControl`. The `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` (sitting in `UserControl`) is property within the `ViewModel`, in `ViewModel` I have a variable that says whether to show a certain line or not, its binding fails, why?

Here my property :

```
private bool _isVisible=false;
public bool IsVisible
{
    get { return _isVisible; }
    set
    {
        _isVisible= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
    }
}
```

When it comes to the function: `NotifyPropertyChanged` the `PropertyChanged` event null - mean he failed to register for the binding.

It should be noted that I have more bindings to `ViewModel` in such a way that works, here is an example:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.Cmd,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`DataGridTemplateColumn` is not part of the visual or logical tree, and therefore has no binding ancestor (or any ancestor) so the `RelativeSource` doesn't work.

Instead you have to give the binding the source explicitly.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding Data.IsVisible, 
    Source={StaticResource proxy},
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

And the binding proxy.

```cs
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
 
    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
 
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), 
        typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

[Credits](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: Now i get this error: BindingExpression path error: 'IsVisible' property not found on 'object' ''BindingProxy'

Comment: Whoops, that should be Data.IsVisible.

Comment: You should be able to use an `ElementName="whatevs"` and avoid this redirection.

Comment: @Will, I tried this way - it did not work.

Comment: @Will ElementName uses the logical tree. When the element doesn't use the logical tree you're SOL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705853/binding-elementname-does-it-use-visual-tree-or-logical-tree

Comment: Outstanding. It’s also the solution in cases where the `ContextMenu` is defined within a custom `TriggerAction`—see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415381/in-mvvm-open-context-menu-upon-drag-completion.