# Binding ToolTip in UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I tried to bind a `ToolTip` text in a `UserControl` this way:

```xml
<Grid.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock
        Text="{
            Binding Path=InfoTT,  
            RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
            }
        }" />
</Grid.ToolTip>
```

And it doesn't work, the `Tooltip` was empty and in logs, I saw:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=InfoTT; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')*

But when I did:

```xml
<Grid
    ToolTip="{
        Binding Path=InfoTT,  
        RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
        }
    }">
</Grid>
```

It worked. Can anyone explain why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: this post might be relevant [cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-relativesource-findancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494226/cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-relativesource-findancestor)

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide some solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `Binding.RelativeSource` doesn't resolve, you can always be sure that the `Binding.Target` is not part of the visual tree.

In your first example you are explicitly defining the tree structure of the `ToolTip`.  You are explicitly creating the content e.g. by adding the `TextBlock`. The content of the `ToolTip` is not part of the visual tree and therefore the `Binding.RelativeSource` can't be resolved.

In your second example, you let the `FrameworkElement` implicitly create the `ToolTip` content.
Now `FrameWorkElement` will first resolve the `Binding`, which resolves, as the `FrameworkElement` is still part of the visual tree. The resolved value is taken, `ToString` invoked, a `TextBlock` created and the string value assigned to `TextBlock.Text`.

### Solution

To solve the binding problem, when implementing the `ToolTip` explicitly, you can implement a [Binding Proxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) as suggested in a comment by @Mark Feldman which makes use of the `StaticResource` markup to provide a `Binding.Source` to elements that are not part of the visual tree.
It's basically a bindable `ObjectDataProvider`.

A similar solution to the binding proxy is to define the content as a resource of the `Grid` and then reference it via `DynamicResource` using a `ContentPresnter`:

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources> 
      <!-- The proxy -->   
      <TextBlock x:Key="ToolTipText" 
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=InfoTT}" />
    <Grid.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource ToolTipText}" />
      </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

But you could also make use of the fact that the `DataContext` is still inherited. Bindings to the `DataContext` will still resolve.

In your scenario, where you want to bind the content of the `ToolTip` to a property of the parent `UserControl`, you could bind this property to a property of the view model, which is the current `DataContext` of `Grid` (and therefore for its `ToolTip`). I only recommend this, when binding to business data and not layout data:

```
<UserControl InfoTT="{Binding ViewModelInfoTT}">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelInfoTT}" />
      </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

If you don't use view models and host the data directly in the control, you may like to set the `DataContext` to the control itself. This way you simplify all bindings and of course can now bind to the `UserControl` from within the `ToolTip`:

```
// Constructor
public MyUserControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // Set the UserControl's DataContext to the control itself
  this.DataContext = this;
}

<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoTT}" />
      </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

Alternatively override the `DataContext`. Of course you'll lose access to the current context:

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestoType=UserControl}>
    <Grid.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoTT}" />
      </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: And if you want to do it the first way then you do it by binding via a [Binding Proxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: @MarkFeldman Thank you for your comment and inspiration. You are right, I should've offered a solution to the problem. I referenced yours alongside some other solutions.

Comment: I did it in the first way. It works perfectly, thanks

Comment: @BionicCode thanks! Very good alternative solution you posted there too, and without an intermediate class. Wouldn't have thought that would work, but there it is.

Comment: Great solution with DynamicResource! Thanks @BionicCode