# How to make controls in 2 DataGridTemplateColumns have equal Heights?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGrid with two DataGridTemplateColumns. In it a ComboBox and a Button. The ComboBox has a normal Height, but the Canvas of the RubbishBinIcon is 200 x 200. So the Button is way too big! If I set the Height and Width by hand to 20, the Button is shrunk to an acceptable size. But I prefer to set the Height to the Height of the ComboBox. This is the XAML:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="X" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="CmbGreenRed" Text="{Binding A}" >
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.G}"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.R}"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button >
                                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="20" Width="20">
                                    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource RubbishBinIcon}" />
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I tried to set the `Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=CmbGreenRed}"` (and Width as well to make the button square) but then I get the Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=CmbGreenRed'.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15494510/1770778) that "DataGridTemplateColumn is not part of the visual or logical tree". So I tried to implement that solution, but I couldn't get it working properly. I had a TwoWay binding to the Height of the Combobox and a OneWay binding to the Height of the Viewbox like the snippets below, but then both controls got too small.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbGreenRed" Height="{Binding Data.CmbGreenRedHeight, Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    ...
</ComboBox>

<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="{Binding Data.CmbGreenRedHeight, Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

So is it possible to reduce the size of the Viewbox to normal proportions without using hard coded numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Either specify a hardcoded height or [bind the actual height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel) of the `ComboBox` to a source property and then bind the `Height` of the `ViewBox` to the same source property:

```
<ComboBox SizeObserver.Observe="True" SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding Height,
    Mode=OneWayToSource}" ...>
...    
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="20">
```